# Dart generics not reified as per the docs

Tags: dart

I'm trying to pass a type in order to make use of the type information, but that types doesn't appear to be pass through.

I went back to the docs to double check that Dart generics are in fact reified and according to the docs, they are:

[image]

I call hydrate on a response which morphs the content of response object:

```
response.hydrate<BoqVO>();
```

I'm expecting `T` to be of type `BoqVO`:

```
class Response { 
    ...
    void hydrate<T>() {
        print(T.runtimeType); // always prints _Type

        if (T is BoqVO) {
            print("IF");
        } else {
            print("ELSE"); // always goes into ELSE block
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

... but it's not.

Replacing `response.hydrate<BoqVO>();` with `response.hydrate(new BoqVO());` and changing the method signature to

```
void hydrate(T t) {
```

works if i now use lowercase `t`, but one shouldn't have to instantiate the object in order for reified generics to be available.

Any ideas why Dart is doing this or what i'm missing for reified generics to work correctly?

PS: I'm not on Dart `2` yet, currently on Dart `1.24.3`

Comment: The doc section you inserted above also is from Dart 1.x? In Dart 1 types were mostly ignored at runtime.

Comment: If i change the dropdown between `Dart 1.24` and `Dart 2`, i see the exact same section, both says generics are reified

Comment: I believe you, but if you refer to specific docs inserting a link to them would be helpful.

Comment: https://v1-dartlang-org.firebaseapp.com/guides/language/language-tour

Comment: Your code is not about collections, it's about generic method type parameters and they definitely weren't reified in Dart 1.

Comment: Ah, bummer, i was under the impression they used collections as an example to show how the generic types are preserved instead of it meaning that it's only supported on collections.
Guess i'll use the instance hack for now until we upgrade to 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic collections were supported from the beginning and they got some type support, but generic methods were only experimental in Dart 1 and reified type parameters were only added in Dart 2 pre releases.

Answer (score 2):

As Günther Zöchbauer has said, the type parameter doesn't work in Dart 1.24.

The following explains what would happen if you tried the same code in Dart 2.0, where it would also not work, because it uses the type parameter incorrectly.

The code `T.runtimeType` treats `T` as an expression. When a type, including a type parameter, is used as an expression, it evaluates to an instance of the class `Type`. What you print is the runtime type of that `Type` object (where `_Type` is an internal platform implementation of `Type`).
To print the real type, just `print(T)` (that still converts `T` to a `Type` object, but one representing the type `BoqVO` and with a `toString` that includes the `BoqVO` name).

Likewise for `T is BoqVO`, you evaluate `T` to a `Type` object, and since `Type` doesn't implement `BoqVO`, that test is always false. There is no simple way to test if the type of a type parameter implements a specific other type, but you can hack around it as `<T>[] is List<BoqVO>`.